# iptable rule to drop packet containing PHP

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to write some iptable rules to drop all packets containing ".php" to avoid seeing that in the logs of my HTTP server:

> 140.143.19.50 - - [10/Feb/2019:20:31:12 +0000] "GET /wp-config.php HTTP/1.1" 404 330 
>   140.143.19.50 - - [10/Feb/2019:20:31:23 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 345 
>   140.143.19.50 - - [10/Feb/2019:20:31:36 +0000] "POST /wp-admins.php HTTP/1.1" 404 330 
>   140.143.19.50 - - [10/Feb/2019:20:32:17 +0000] "POST /tomcat.php HTTP/1.1" 404 327 
>   140.143.19.50 - - [10/Feb/2019:20:34:19 +0000] "GET /admin/mysql/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 338 
>   140.143.19.50 - - [10/Feb/2019:20:34:19 +0000] "GET /admin/mysql2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 339 
>   140.143.19.50 - - [10/Feb/2019:20:34:21 +0000] "GET /admin/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 343 
>   140.143.19.50 - - [10/Feb/2019:20:34:22 +0000] "GET /admin/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 343 
>   140.143.19.50 - - [10/Feb/2019:20:34:23 +0000] "GET /admin/phpmyadmin2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 344 
>   140.143.19.50 - - [10/Feb/2019:20:34:23 +0000] "GET /mysqladmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 337

I use the following rules:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 100 --algo bm --string '.php' -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m string --to 100 --algo bm --string '.php' -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 100 --algo bm --string '.php' -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m string --to 100 --algo bm --string '.php' -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 100 --algo bm --string '.php' -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -m string --to 100 --algo bm --string '.php' -j DROP
```

I thought that those rules would be enough, I expected that the packets containing PHP would be dropped but I keep having those packets that bloat my logs. I use Jetty, I don't need PHP on my server. How can I get rid of the packets above once for all?

Comment: Netfilter string patch was intended for sending packets to another IDS instead of taking care of the traffic itself.
https://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html

Maybe you should switch to a proper IDS/IPS? Then I would suggest Suricata (https://suricata-ids.org/). BTW consider it will only work on unencrypted protocols.

Comment: @realpclaudio Thank you, maybe I'm using the wrong tool for this task.